# Where do i put the effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

Finally if found the right jquery script that i need.

But i want to change the effect, now it's coming from the top-left corner and i want to let it slide to the left.

This is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        //add the click event to each element with the toggle class 
        $('a.toggle').click(function(){
            if ($(document).data("toggle-id")) {
                //item was already selected, hide it
                $("div.toggle#" + $(document).data("toggle-id")).hide(1000);
            }
            //save the new id for later, then show it
            $(document).data("toggle-id", $(this).text().toLowerCase());
            $("div.toggle#" + $(document).data("toggle-id")).show(1000)
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What have you attempted? What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: Nothing is wrong but i want to know how to change the effect to slide

Comment: I'd consider reading some of the jQuery docs; might be helpful.

Comment: Try making an attempt to solve the problem -- if you run into difficulty, then come back and let us know what you've tried and what issues you're running into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify this line

```
$("div.toggle#" + $(document).data("toggle-id")).show(1000)
```

And try something like

```
$("div.toggle#" + $(document).data("toggle-id")).show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000)
```

Comment: Excellent please mark the question resolved.